# Excel VBA: How do I delete images in a specific range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that imports data from a selected file. The data includes some images. The problem I am having is if i have data and images already in my document, and I go to import new data, the images do not delete and simply get pasted on top of each other. I wrote code to select the cells and clear them, but it doesn't clear the images.

I think the solution is to put some code at the beginning that can select the images in the cell range and delete them, before the new data is imported.

I came across a solution that Selects all images in the worksheet and deletes them, But I have other images that I need to keep.

Is is possible to tell it to select all images in a specific range of cells?

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search (most questions have been asked in one place or another) came up with this result. It uses the TopLeftCell and BottomRightCell attributes of Excel Picture objects, then checks if it is inside the range.

```
Sub test()
'Code by Peter T from https://www.excelbanter.com/excel-programming/404480-select-delete-all-pictures-given-range.html
Dim s As String
Dim pic As Picture
Dim rng As Range

' Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Set rng = ws.Range("A5:C25")

For Each pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
    With pic
        s = .TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & .BottomRightCell.Address
    End With
    If Not Intersect(rng, ws.Range(s)) Is Nothing Then
        pic.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I have not tested this code, but even so it should provide you with enough information to adjust your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I too came across this but was having issues with it. With more research, I was able to get this code to do what I wanted it to,

```
Sub DeleteImage()

Dim pic As Picture

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

For Each pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
    If Not Application.Intersect(pic.TopLeftCell, range("H10:R24")) Is Nothing Then
        pic.Delete
    End If

Next pic

End Sub
```